# Python executes statements under If condition even though the If condition is false

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, visual-studio-code

```
            if str(orders_pnl.iloc[i,0])[-2:]=='CE': 
                if orders_pnl.iloc[i,5]=='N':
                    c=error(str(orders_pnl.iloc[i,0])[-2:],str(ce))
```

Now even though the 1st if value condition is false, it still directly goes to 3rd statement, doesnt check the 2nd if statement as well.

I have attached the screenshot as well for reference. And this is not specic to this If statement and condition, it is happening for most if statements.

[image]

Ideally the If statement should not be executed

Comment: It should not be executed. Can you check if there isn't a problem with the indentation?

Comment: The indentation is just fine as you can see from the screenshot. I am going mad with this error.